# Ensure a Rules Link only shows in a set type within a Panel Page (Drupal)

Tags: drupal, drupal-rules, drupal-panels

I've created a Rules Link (in a View) which shows in a users dashboard using Drupal v.7.27 as CMS for a number of (similar) projects using the same functionality. The Rules Link is set to 'trigger' a rule when the user clicks "Post Content" (the Rules Link). The Rules link works fine and fires the trigger which then follows the simple conditions I've set and only because I've created Variant Panel pages for each User Type, the Rules Link only shows on the ones I've set the Panels Page Access conditions (ie Role: Content Manager).

However, I've noticed that as I'm also using the Support Ticket Module, then "Post Content" Rules Link is also showing on the top of the list of a users Support Tickets list (only for testing here, but it's shows my test comments from both user and Admin user) AND* it also shows on a link on all other Node types.
Clearly I don't want the Rules Link to show at the top or bottom of any other content type other than a Node (ie on the Post New Content Panel Page). At the moment is set within the Rules "Edit Bundle" section to show across 'none' as there is no option to force it to show ONLY on my Dashboard Panel. I'm also using the 'Render' Rules option and tried every option but to no avail after a few hours.

I've had to set the option to 'Nodes' in the Entity type which the Rules Link is attached to (because my Article data is a Node within the Panel Page) and it says quote:
*'Bundles to which the link should be attached to. If left empty, the link is not restricted for any bundles' under the Bundles section.'*

Furthermore, within the Views entity created (used to set the 'Rules Link' into any Node), there is no option that I can find which enforces the Rules Link to only be limited to a particular node, which in my case is a custom Page Panel. Maybe I lack current Drupal knowledge or simply have over looked an issue.

I know I need to learn PHP (yes, currently working through CodeAcademy!) but in order to get the thing working functionally, can anyone advise on what is going wrong and why the Rules Link is showing n other Node types and for a PHP novice like me at this stage, could I simply put some PHP in somewhere that would ensure the Rules Link only shows on a set Content Panel on my custom Panel Page.

I hope I have been clear enough and help at this stage is most gratefully received. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
Actually the Rules Link is showing on all other Nodes (see above*). I've noticed that Bundles might be the key here? I've todate not used Bundles if that helps anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RESOLVED**

I found the source of the problem.
The answer is to ensure that the "Render Entity" is un-ticked in the option box:

"Show link when entity is rendered
If checked,the link is shown when viewing an entity to which the bundle and the visibility conditions apply. Only applies to displayed entity types and if no addition variables were added."

I hope that helps any future readers.